# Avoid implicit arguments of Fixpoint from becoming explicit in proof mode

Tags: coq

Is there a way to enforce Fixpoint implicit arguments to remain implicit in proof mode?

Example:

```
Fixpoint foo {a : Set} (l : list a) : nat :=
  match l with
  | nil => 1
  | _ :: xs => ltac:(exact (1 + foo _ xs))
                                   ^^^  
end.
```

But I would like to write

```
Fixpoint foo {a : Set} (l : list a) : nat :=
  match l with
  | nil => 1
  | _ :: xs => ltac:(exact (1 + foo xs))
  end.
```

Comment: I am tempted to say "no", but it wouldn't surprise me if no one's had this issue before. You're probably better off posting an issue on GitHub (https://github.com/coq/coq/issues).

Comment: [Someone appears to have asked after this before.](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/4573) It was closed as wontfix. The reason given for this failure is that "local definitions do not carry any information about their arguments" and it was not expected that this would ever change.

Comment: @HTNW Your comment looks like an answer to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people have been saying I don't think it will be implemented but in some cases I believe you can circumvent the issue using sections.

```
From Coq Require Import List.
Import ListNotations.

Section Foo.

  Context {a : Set}.

  Fixpoint foo (l : list a) : nat :=
    match l with
    | nil => 1
    | _ :: xs => ltac:(exact (1 + foo xs))
    end.

End Foo.
```

Note that this is equivalent (in that it produces the same definition) as:

```
Definition foo' {a : Set} :=
  fix foo' (l : list a) : nat :=
    match l with
    | nil => 1
    | _ :: xs => ltac:(exact (1 + foo' xs))
    end.
```

Here the trick is more explicit, you take the argument `a : Set` before doing a fixed-point.

Of course this only works when the implicit argument in question is uniform in the definition.